# how to add an xblock as a course tab in edx platform

Tags: edx

I've installed the devstack on my local machine.
I am planning to add a chat functionality to edx platform where students could contact instructors of the course. (Just a simple page that lists all instructors of the course with a link to chat them)
I tried using xblock and successfully created one. But it appears xblock is for custom course contents which are injected as units in the courseware.
What I want is to add a course tab which will appear for every course which lists all instructors students can consult to via chat.
Is it possible via xblock? If not, could you please suggest other options to achieve what I want?

Comment: Please ask on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/edx-code

Answer (score 1):

Full tutorial: https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/AC/Adding+a+new+course+tab

Add an entry point like this to your Python library's *setup.py*. Note that `new_tab` is the id of your tab, and `example.NewTab` is the fully qualified name of your new tab class.

```
entry_points={
    "openedx.course_tab": [
        "new_tab = example.NewTab",
    }
}
```

Define the new tab class as a subclass of `CourseTab` and declare its properties:

```
from courseware.tabs import CourseTab


class NewTab(CourseTab):
    """A new course tab."""

    name = "new_tab"
    title = ugettext_noop("New Tab")  # We don't have the user in this context, so we don't want to translate it at this level.
    view_name = "new_tab_view"

    @classmethod
    def is_enabled(cls, course, user=None):
        """Returns true if this tab is enabled."""
        return settings.FEATURES.get('NEW_TAB_ENABLED', False)
```

Relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/edx-code/sE63D12V4Xc/78VRqMipBwAJ

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/edx-code/ji-_w-nbu7c